# What should be the ratio between number of cases and attributes in multivariate regression?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, sample-size, regression-strategies, multivariate-regression

Is there any way to determine if it is feasible to perform a multivariate regression based on  a given number of samples and attributes?
For example I have a data set with 6 cases , 30 attributes and 5 targets. How can I make sure that it's possible to get an acceptable result with this data set and if not,  what should be the ratio between cases and attributes?

Answer (score 1):

In traditional terminology I assume you have 30 predictors and a sample size of 6 subjects.  I'm not sure what "targets" are; perhaps you mean dependent variables.  If I have understood this correctly you do not have a worthwhile sample had you had to deal with only one target.  The minimum sample size needed to estimate the mean of a single $Y$ with no predictors is typically several dozen observations.  So you are not able to even estimate the model intercept.  Then you need something like 15 observations per *candidate* predictor if your signal:noise ratio is not very high.

In ordinary regression the sample size needed to just estimate the residual standard deviation with a multiplicative margin of error of 1.2 is $n=70$.

Comment: Thank you Frank. As you mentioned correctly, by target I meant dependent variables.